# Using Jekyll's Collection relative_directory for organizing pages/collections

Tags: jekyll

I thought that setting the `relative_directory` [(Jekyll Collection Docs)](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/#liquid-attributes) [(github PR)](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/3723) property being set would help me keep my files organized without compromising my desired output, but it seems to be ignored/not used for producing files. I don't want my collections to be in the root directory, because I find it confusing to have ~10 collection folders adjacent to `_assets`, `_data`, `_includes`, `_layouts`, and others.

Fixes or alternative solutions are welcomed, as long as long as the output is the same, and my pages are in their own directory, without needing to put `permalink` front-matter on every single page.

**_config.yaml**

```
collections:
  root:
    relative_directory: '_pages/root'
    output: true
    permalink: /:path.html
  root-worthy:
    relative_directory: '_pages/root-worthy'
    output: true
    permalink: /:path.html
  docs:
    relative_directory: '_pages/docs'
    output: true
    permalink: /docs/:path.html
```

**Directory Structure:**

```
├── ...
├── _layouts
├── _pages
│   ├── root
│   │   ├── about.html
│   │   └── contact.html
│   ├── root_worthy
│   │   ├── quickstart.html
│   │   └── seo-worthy-page.html
│   └── docs
│       ├── errors.html
│       └── api.html
├── _posts
└── index.html
```

**Desired output:**

```
├── ...
├── _site
│   ├── about.html
│   ├── contact.html
│   ├── quickstart.html
│   ├── seo-worthy-page.html
│   └── docs
│       ├── errors.html
│       └── api.html
└── ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the PR you mention is still not merged.

For 3.1.6 and next 3.2, [jekyll code is still](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/blob/master/lib/jekyll/collection.rb#L101) :

```
@relative_directory ||= "_#{label}"
```

But [the requester made a plugin](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/pull/3723#issuecomment-127459530) that looks like this :

**_plugins/collection_relative_directory.rb**

```
module Jekyll
  class Collection
    def relative_directory
      @relative_directory ||= (metadata['relative_directory'] && site.in_source_dir(metadata['relative_directory']) ||  "_#{label}")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for catching my mistake (not being merged yet). Unfortunately the relative_directory plugin that's there still doesn't help me output files to the path that I want. The :path variable ends up including the whole relative_directory so that I get urls like www.example.com/collection/_pages/collection/page.html

Comment: did you ever find a fix for this?